# Make multiple class object members of another class in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I am having a trouble of putting multiple class objects as member of another class. To be more specific: lets assume we have 2 classes, A and B and class A is nested. I want the main function to have an array with 3 objects of class B. The first object will have 2 objects of class A, the second object will have 5 objects of class A and the third object will have 7 objects of class A. How can i do that? Below is one of my thoughts:

```
Class A{

private:
   int variable;

public:
   A(){
       cout<< A created! <<endl;
   }

  ~A(){
       cout<< A destructed! <<endl;
   }

};


Class B{

private:
   A array[6]; //It will always create 6 elements of class A...

public:
   B(){
       cout<< B created! <<endl;
   }

  ~B(){
       cout<< B destructed! <<endl;
   }

};

int main(){

B* array[3];

for (i = 0 ; i <= 2 ; i++)
{
    array[i] = new B(); //Every B element in array have 6 elements of class A
}

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `std::vector` and create some insert method to access outside of B that inserts an `A` in that vector.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!Yes vectors is a good implementation but this is a project that we are not allowed to use them..

Comment: Then it's a bad class and they're teaching you C, not C++. Anyway, you only resort is dynamic allocation then.

Comment: @GillBates: Not neccessarily a bad class: Only after having experienced the horrors of dynamic allocation, you can really appreciate the benefits of the STL.

Comment: @FrankPuffer Yea you could also make them write OOP in C, to make them appreciate support for class syntax and automatic memory management for members. You can make people suffer learning useless stuff to appreciate the goodness of higher level, but should that really be the point of a class?

Comment: @luk32  I see too many of these restrictions, but the most egregious is to be told "you can't use std::string".  That one makes no sense whatsoever, and I am tempted to post a simple string class just to thwart this ridiculous restriction.

Comment: Also, the issue of teaching C++ this way almost certainly guarantees whatever enthusiasm many new C++ programmer may have had goes out the window, and they go take up Java.  Who the heck wants to write all of this code for a "dynamic array" or unwieldly `new char [x]` all over the place and never getting their programs to work.

Comment: @luk32: "should that really be the point of a class?" - no, of course not. I also agree that these restrictions are overdone in many classes. Still, you do have `new` and `delete` in C++ and these are used internally by the STL. In some rare cases you have to use elementary language features like these yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `B` a parameterised type (I think that's the correct term):

```
template<int a>
class B {
  A array[a];      
};

int main() {
  B<2> b1;
  B<5> b2;
  B<7> b3;
}
```

However they can't be in an array as `B<2>` is a different type to `B<7>` etc.

Comment: Although forbidding vectors and allowing templates would be a bit like banning rifles and allowing machine-guns :D

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use vectors.. (which you should).. here is a working example that shows what you want to do with arrays and manual memory management. https://ideone.com/KihmON

Note: there is no error handling in here. If this was your program it's very unlikely `new` will ever fail, but for larger objects it can. If you thrown an error in main before your `delete` statements, those objects will never get deleted. That is why `vector` is preferred, in the case of errors, it will get cleaned up when it leaves scope no matter what.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
private:
   int variable;

public:
   A()
   {
      std::cout << "A created!" << std::endl;
   }

   ~A()
   {
      std::cout << "A destructed!" << std::endl;
   }

};

class B
{
private:
   size_t arrayOnHeapSize; // size of array on heap
   A* arrayOnHeap; // memory must be allocated before this is used.

public:
   B(size_t arrSize) :
      arrayOnHeapSize(arrSize)
   {
      arrayOnHeap = new A[arrSize]; // must deallocate memory manually, use "delete[]" arrays of objects
      std::cout<< "B created with size" << arrSize << '!' << std::endl;
   }

   ~B()
   {
      delete[] arrayOnHeap; // must deallocate memory manually
      std::cout << "B destructed! Wouldn't have had to do memory management manually if I had used a vector!" << std::endl;
   }

   B(const B&) = delete; // If you need to make a copy, you'll have to make a copy constructor that performs a deep copy or adds some (ugly) reference counting logic. Could also opt to implement a move constructor. If you copied this as is, the pointer will get copied, one B will get destructed freeing the memory, then the other B will have a dangling pointer and try to free that upon destruction. No good.

};

int main()
{
   B* arrayOfB[3];
   arrayOfB[0] = new B(2);
   arrayOfB[0] = new B(5);
   arrayOfB[0] = new B(7);
   delete arrayOfB[0]; // must deallocate manually, using "delete" instead of "delete[]" because these are each 1 object, not arrays.
   delete arrayOfB[1];
   delete arrayOfB[2];
   // Don't need to delete arrayOfB as it is a local on the stack and will be taken care of as the function exits.
}
```

Comment: `B` needs a copy con too

Comment: @GillBates true... another reason to use vectors.